# Arduino with ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have completed the circuit and code to interface ESP8266 module with Arduino UNO.

When i send `AT`,`AT+RST` from serial monitor the reply is correct .

But when i send AT commands to search WIFI networks (`AT+CWLAP`) & connect to WIFI (`AT+CWJAP="SSID","password"`) the reply is `ERROR`.

But the IP address (may be default) is obtained as `192.168.4.1`
 when i send `AT+CIFSR` .

Here is my code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.  
                             // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2  
                             // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3  

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different
}

void loop()
{
    if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message
    {
        while(esp8266.available())
        {
            // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
            char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
            Serial.write(c);
        }
    }
    if(Serial.available())
    {
        // the following delay is required because otherwise the arduino will read the first letter of the command but not the rest
        // In other words without the delay if you use AT+RST, for example, the Arduino will read the letter A send it, then read the rest and send it
        // but we want to send everything at the same time.
        delay(1000);
        String command="";
        while(Serial.available()) // read the command character by character
        {
            // read one character
            command+=(char)Serial.read();
        }
        esp8266.println(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
    }
}
```

Comment: Your serial reading code, with that really horrible delay, is not good.  You should read and digest this: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino

Comment: You want to use  `AT+CWSAP="SSID","password",1,0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i found the solution .

Send `AT+CWMODE=1` first , then all other commands working fine.