# Error on sending AT+CWJAP_DEF commands to ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am trying to send `AT` commands to `ESP8266` to get connected with internet with the Wifi.

When I am sending `AT` and `AT+RST` command on serial monitor then I am getting OK and ready response which seems perfect.

Then I am sending `AT+CWLAP` to get list of available wifi networks which is also executing correctly.

```
AT+CWLAP

+CWLAP:(3,"Moto",-42,"a4:70:d6:7a:fa:6c",1,25,0)
+CWLAP:(4,"PRANJAL",-95,"1c:a5:32:3d:f5:c4",1,-16,0)
+CWLAP:(2,"VIHAN",-94,"c8:3a:35:2f:1d:81",1,-21,0)
+CWLAP:(3,"Tenda",-93,"c8:3a:35:20:a9:b1",9,-4,0)

OK
```

Then I sent `AT+CWMODE?` which is also perfect.

```
AT+CWMODE?

+CWMODE:1

OK
```

Now I am trying to connect `ESP8266` with above listed Wifi with this command, it is sending an ERROR on serial monitor.

> AT+CWJAP_DEF="Moto","reset1234"

**Error**

```
⸮=IRe"Moto","reset1234"

ERROR
```

Can anyone suggest me what could be the reason of this issue ?at

Comment: Don't [cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809639/error-on-sending-atcwjap-def-commands-to-esp8266).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! I just tried to connect with different wifi and it got connected with it. It was some kinda issue with mobile hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

The source of such problems are mostly as under

- Bad / loose wiring (power and communication)
- software serial is not much reliable
- Arduino serial monitor is not a user friendly way of testing out ESP modue

To solve wiring related problems for good check out [this design](http://absaransari.com/2018/01/25/how-to-power-esp8266-from-5v-supply/).

To solve communication monitoring problems check out [this solution](http://absaransari.com/2018/01/27/esp8266-wifi-module-configuration-utility/)

Use USB to TTL interface to connect ESP module directly to your PC without using an Arduino ([find details here](http://absaransari.com/2018/01/26/connecting-esp8266-wifi-mobile-with-computer-using-pl2303/))

Answer (score 0):

Based on the gibberish echo, the possible causes are:

- Insufficient power. You need a source that can supply up to 300mA which is about the max consumption for the module. A good-sized capacitor across the ESP power rails (10uF maybe) wouldn't hurt.
- Baud rate is too high. If you're using an Arduino as 'middle-man' and talking to the ESP8266 through a SoftwareSerial port, you're likely to face this sort of issue if the baud rate is as high as 115200; SoftwareSerial is unreliable at such rates.

Comment: I connected VCC and CH_PD to 3.3 V, should I connect GPIO0 and GPIO1 also to 3.3 V ? and ESP8266 baud rate is 9600

Comment: I connected GPIO0 and GPIO1 to 3.3V and your solution is not working :(

Comment: @Williams What solution? I didn't mention GPIO pins. I asked you to provide a better power source to it or reduce the baud rate. Which did you do?

Comment: My baud rate is already 9600 and VCC and CH_PD to 3.3 V. How I can provide better power? can you please suggest

Comment: @Williams How are you powering it at the moment?

Comment: I connected VCC and CH_PD of ESP8266 to 3.3 V of Arduino, GND to GND

Comment: @Williams Do you have an LM1117T regulator? Or any other 3.3V regulator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58309/discussion-between-williams-and-tisteandii).